# GAE handling simple http post request (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, http-post

i'm trying to make out with web-apps on java using google app engine. i have an application that is sending http-post request.

- what should my web-app looks like to handle this http-post request?
- what url should i use in HttpPost if my web-app gae url is http://example.appspot.com/example_app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a [servlet on GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html) that handles the POST:

   ```
   public class ExampleAppServlet extends HttpServlet{
       public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

           // get some data from POST
           InputStream input = req.getInputStream();

           // do something with input

           // send back some reply
           resp.getWriter().write("Hello Example App").close();
       } 
   }
   ```
2. Map this servlet to URL in [`web.xml` config file](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html):

   ```
   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
       <servlet>
           <servlet-name>example_app_servlet</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>com.package.ExampleAppServlet</servlet-class>
       </servlet>
       <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>example_app_servlet</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/example_app</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
   </web-app>
   ```